# BibLaTex changes name for resource

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

So I got an online resource in my bibliography, alphabetic style using Biber:

```
@online{Cpp20,
    title        = {ISO/IEC 14882:2020 Programming languages — C++},
    organization = {ISO},
    date         = {2020-03-31},
    urldate = {2022-08-28},
    url = {https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf},
}
```

When compiled, BibLaTex generates this entry in the bibliography page:

[image]

Why does it trim out the leading "Cpp"?

Comment: Could you explain more about what you mean? I don't see any "trimmed out" "Cpp". What were you expecting?

Comment: I expected the reference not being [20] but [Cpp20]. I thought the first word after the curly braces will be the reference name. Or did I get this entirely wrong and those names are autogenerated?

Comment: Without a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), it's hard to know what to expect, but usually with the alphabetic style, I'd expect the abbreviation to be based not on the citation key, but on the author and year fields. You don't have an author field in that entry. If you want to set the shorthand manually, you could try `shorthand = {Cpp20},`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Misunderstood the usage of the first text after the opening curly...

Comment: I would change the title of this to "Biblatex - how to customise the label"

Answer (score 1):

The label isn't determined from the citation key but is highly customisable and is determined from just about any of the citation data you wish. The default is:

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}
```

There are two parts to this label - `shorthand` OR `label` OR (parts of)
`labelname` if only one name OR (parts) of `labelname` if more than one
name PLUS (part of) `year`. Since you have no fields corresponding to
the first part, there is only the second part which is composed of the
two rightmost digits of `year`, hence the label `20`. If you **really** want to use the citation key, you can put this in your preamble:

```
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field{citekey}
  }
}
```